# Unable to build sqlcipher in Xcode: missing sqlite3.c

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlcipher

I am unable to build sqlcipher (latest git-source) on Xcode (5.0), it's failing with:

> clang: error: no such file or directory: ..../sqlite.c

I'm trying to build for iOS (5, with the v7 SDK).
openssl, openssl-xcode & sqlcipher are included as sub- projects as per documentation, targets of sqlcipher are sqlcipher and amalgamation, but for some reason the sqlite3.c is not being built.
Any ideas where to look further? I'm not an xcode expert... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to the guys of the sqlcipher project this has been resolved:
I went by the [tutorial on the sqlcipher.net site](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/) rather than reading the [README](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/blob/master/README.md) ;)

Speaking - put everything in place, go with the good old command prompt in the sqlcipher root directory and set off the following:

```
$ ./configure --enable-tempstore=yes CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC" \
LDFLAGS="-lcrypto"
$ make
```

This builds the missing files and you're ready to build the whole thing!